# Check whether the array contains in array of arrays in LINQ expression

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have some problem with my unit test which work with fake Context(means without database connection). On productive environment it work with connection to sql and everything is clear. But with fake context happened something strange - not find array "item.OfferKey" in the array of arrays "validCartItems"

```
//Array of arrays validCartItems values for example
byte[] offerKey1 = { 30, 163, 252, 225, 36, 208, 128, 47, 64, 244, 34, 199, 28, 57, 110, 215 };
byte[] offerKey2 = { 31, 163, 254, 225, 35, 203, 119, 47, 65, 244, 24, 199, 28, 56, 110, 215 };
byte[][] validCartItems = new byte[4][];
validCartItems[0] = offerKey1;
validCartItems[1] = offerKey1;
validCartItems[2] = offerKey1;
validCartItems[3] = offerKey2;

//Example of ItemPrice in _dataContext.ItemPrices
var itemPriceInFakeContext = new ItemPrice()
{
    OfferKey = offerKey1,
    //some other properties            
};

var itemPrices = _dataContext
    .ItemPrices
    .Where(item => 
         item.UserID == user.UniqueID
         && itemsPartID.Contains(item.PartID)
         && validCartItems.Contains(item.OfferKey)
         && item.CurrencyID == defaultCurrencyCode
         && item.Inventory > 0)
    .ToList();
```

In this case no elements found. But in case we work with database everithing is all right.

To solve the problem, I wrote the following code:

```
var itemPricesUncheckOfferKey = _dataContext
    .ItemPrices
    .Where(item => 
         item.UserID == user.UniqueID
         && itemsPartID.Contains(item.PartID)
         //&& validCartItems.Contains(item.OfferKey)
         && item.CurrencyID == defaultCurrencyCode
         && item.Inventory > 0)
    .ToList();

List<ItemPrice> itemPrices = new List<ItemPrice>();
foreach (var itemPrice in itemPricesUncheckOfferKey)
{
    foreach (var validCartItem in validCartItems.Distinct())
    {
        if (validCartItem.SequenceEqual(itemPrice.OfferKey))
            itemPrices.Add(itemPrice);
    }
 }
```

But it does not look like a good solution. Could you tell me the solution within LINQ?

UPD

UnitTest code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddCartItems_Test()
{
    User user;
    InitUser(out user);

    List<AddCartItem> addCartItems;
    addCartItems = InitAddCartItem();

    ICartService cartService;
    InitCartService(out cartService);

    List<AddCartItemRezult> addCartItemRezults = cartService.AddCartItems(user, addCartItems);

    Assert.AreEqual(4, addCartItemRezults.Count);
    int countAllGood = 0;
    foreach (var addCartItemRezult in addCartItemRezults)
    {
        if (addCartItemRezult.IsSuccess) countAllGood++;
    }
    Assert.AreEqual(1, countAllGood);
}

 private void InitCartService(out ICartService cartService )
    {
        DataFakeContext dataFakeContext = new DataFakeContext();
        DataContext_InitUsers(ref dataFakeContext);
        DataContext_ItemPrices(ref dataFakeContext);
        DataContext_CartItems(ref dataFakeContext);

        IDeliveryService deliveryService = new DeliveryFakeService(dataFakeContext);

        cartService = new CartService(dataFakeContext, deliveryService);
    }

private void DataContext_ItemPrices(ref DataFakeContext dataFakeContext)
    {
        dataFakeContext.ItemPrices = new ItemPriceDbSet();

        byte[] OfferKeyPriv = { 30, 163, 252, 225, 36, 208, 128, 47, 64, 244, 34, 199, 28, 57, 110, 215 };
        var itemPrice1 = new DataAccess.Sql.NavisionModel.ItemPrice()
        {
            Inventory = 2075,
            ItemID = "475931",
            LineAmount = (decimal)389.9300,
            LineAmountWithMargin = (decimal)522.5062,                                
            Multiplicity = 1,                
            OfferKey = OfferKeyPriv,
            //some other properties
        };

        dataFakeContext.ItemPrices.Add(itemPrice1);
    }
```

I use Repository.Pattern.Ef6;

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the same object of `byte[]` in your `validCartItems` and in your fake `_dataContext.ItemPrices` objects ?

Comment: I just tested it (with the same object) and it works properly.

Comment: I recheck validCartItems and _dataContext.ItemPrices (take one element from list and see OfferKey). validCartItems is byte[][]  OfferKeyis byt[].

Comment: Can you add your unit test code? I'm curious who do you return `itemPriceInFakeContext` from `_dataContext.ItemPrices`.

Comment: I added some code. Is it enough? All code is very big.

Comment: In your code you're creating `byte[] OfferKeyPriv = ...` and saving it into `itemPrice1`. And you should use the same variable to adding this into your `validCartItems`. I mean **exactly** the same - not the save value but the reference to the same object.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I followed your advice and now everything is working correctly. How to put a plus to your comment? Or may be write anwer for other.

Comment: I just summarized all these comments and put the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're creating `byte[] offerKey1 = ...` and saving it into `itemPriceInFakeContext`. And you should use the same variable to adding this into your _dataContext. I mean **exactly the same** - not the save value but the **reference to the same object**.

Like this:

```
//Array of arrays validCartItems values for example
byte[] offerKey1 = { 30, 163, 252, 225, 36, 208, 128, 47, 64, 244, 34, 199, 28, 57, 110, 215 };
byte[] offerKey2 = { 31, 163, 254, 225, 35, 203, 119, 47, 65, 244, 24, 199, 28, 56, 110, 215 };
byte[][] validCartItems = new byte[4][];
validCartItems[0] = offerKey1;
validCartItems[1] = offerKey1;
validCartItems[2] = offerKey1;
validCartItems[3] = offerKey2;

//Example of ItemPrice in _dataContext.ItemPrices
var itemPriceInFakeContext = new ItemPrice()
{
    OfferKey = offerKey1, // use the same object
    //some other properties            
};

// add fake item price to data context
_dataContext.ItemPrices.Add(itemPriceInFakeContext );

var itemPrices = _dataContext
    .ItemPrices
    .Where(item => 
         item.UserID == user.UniqueID
         && itemsPartID.Contains(item.PartID)
         && validCartItems.Contains(item.OfferKey)
         && item.CurrencyID == defaultCurrencyCode
         && item.Inventory > 0)
    .ToList();
```

That should help.

p.s. you faced this problem because of differences between how runtime compares `byte[]` and how it does `EF` and `SQL`. 
In runtime it compares by references. But your LINQ query (on executing) converts this `byte[]` array (I believe) into the string. And on SQL side it compares the string which will be compared by value.

Comment: I cannot give you plus because have not enough reputation(need 15). It was my first question on stackoverflow. But I will try to put a plus later. Thank you, you helped me a lot.

Comment: There should be the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemPrices = _dataContext
    .ItemPrices
    .Where(item => 
         item.UserID == user.UniqueID
         && itemsPartID.Contains(item.PartID)
         && validCartItems.Contains(item.OfferKey)
         && item.CurrencyID == defaultCurrencyCode
         && item.Inventory > 0)
    .ToList();
```

Your LINQ query seems to have no error in it. Please check the dataContext if it is initialized and whether the connection to the database is ok.

Comment: I check before write answer. "On productive environment it work with connection to sql and everything is clear." On test sql server it's work good too. As I know problem only with fake context(

Comment: Fine. Good to know that everything is fine.

Comment: Unfortunately not everything is fine( The same code don't work correctly on unit test with Fake Context without sql connection.